# <fstream> and <algorithm> transform

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, fstream

I need to read a text file into transform() using stream iterator adapters. I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

I'm getting this error in algorithm...

```
binary '=' : no operator defined which takes a left-hand operand of  type 'const std::basic_string<char>,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Here's some of the code:

```
ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;
set<string, AscDictSort> set1, set2, modSet1, modSet2;

fin.open("infile1.txt");
if (fin.is_open())
{
    transform(istream_iterator<string>(fin), istream_iterator<string>(), set1.cbegin(), punctRemover);
}
fin.close();
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Replace `set1.cbegin()` with `std::inserter(set1, set1.begin())`

Comment: I get the same error, I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: [Proof of concept](http://rextester.com/RBXWI68442). If you'd like further help, show [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here's the error. I included AscDictSort and punctremover as well. http://rextester.com/UDZXB10445

Comment: @Derprecitus: Your code, modified according to Igor's suggestion: http://rextester.com/VJNAE11521 -- No errors.

Comment: That's strange, maybe visual studio is just being weird. I'm going to restart the project and check again.

Comment: Yeah, after creating a fresh project, it seems to be working.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't create `fin`, call `open`, and call `close`. The constructor for `ifstream` can open the file, and the destructor will close it. Also, you don't need to explicitly call `is_open()`; stream objects are implicitly convertible to `bool`, and that conversion tests the validity of the stream. `ifstream fin("infile1.txt");` and `if(fin)` are all you need.